# Can not give host name to website via IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, razor-pages, hostname

I developed a website using .net core Razor Pages. I want to publish the website from the server using IIS. Now the website is only reachable by IP address and port number because when I give hostname it does not work. I got an error that "could not connect to server".  I tried everything and could not find any solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Édit your question to include IIS settings for this site please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the IP address to All Unassigned, this will enable the All local NICs can be accessed by the IP address, as well as the hostname. The hostname should be accord with the below properties.
[image]
[image]
If it doesn’t work, we should check if the hostname is available in the network connectivity.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.